# Golang Error Types are empty when encoded to JSON

Tags: json, go, struct

I'm trying to encode some JSON for a REST api, everything is working fine except for some errors. For example, with this struct:

```
type TemplateResponse struct {
    Message string
    Error   error
    Template Template
}
```

Encoded with this data:

```
res := TemplateResponse{"Template not found.", fmt.Errorf("There is no template on this host with the name " + vars["name"]), Template{}}
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(res)
```

Returns:

```
{
  "Message": "Template not found.",
  "Error": {},
  "Template": {
    "Name": "",
    "Disabled": false,
    "Path": "",
    "Version": ""
  }
}
```

I'm getting this seemingly randomly across my application, where 'error' types are being returned as empty. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Because [`error`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error) is just an interface. It may hold a value of any concrete type that implements it.

In your example you used [`fmt.Errorf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Errorf) to create an `error` value. That calls [`errors.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#example_New) which returns a pointer to a value of the unexported `errors.errorString` struct. Its definition is:

```
type errorString struct {
    s string
}
```

This struct value will be marshaled, but since it has no exported fields (only exported fields are marshaled), it will be an empty JSON object: `{}`.

The "fix" is: don't marshal values of "general" interfaces, relying on that the dynamic values can be marshaled into JSON meaningfully. Instead you should add a field that stores the error string (the result of `error.Error()`), and omit the `Error error` field from marshaling, e.g.:

```
type TemplateResponse struct {
    Message  string
    Error    error `json:"-"`
    ErrorMsg string
    Template Template
}
```

Of course then you also need to set / fill the `ErrorMsg` field before marshaling.

Or if you don't need to store the `error` value in the struct, remove that field completely:

```
type TemplateResponse struct {
    Message  string
    ErrorMsg string
    Template Template
}
```

If you still want to keep the `Error error` field (and not the `ErrorMsg` field), then you need to implement a custom marshaling logic by implementing the [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) interface where you can "convert" the `error` value to a meaningful `string` for example (or into another value that can be marshaled properly).

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks very much for the great explanation!

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been writing go code on and off for years and never hit this problem until today. You've saved me hours of debugging. I was receiving input from a black box and the input kept showing nil and crashing during unmarshalling. I was starting to lose my mind.