# How to write a generic function that takes a string or an error as a parameter?

Tags: go, generics

Is there any way to take a string or an error as a generic parameter?

```golang
package controller

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type ServerError[T fmt.Stringer] struct {
    Reason T `json:"reason"`
}

func ResponseWithBadRequest[T fmt.Stringer](c *gin.Context, reason T) {
    c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, ServerError[T]{Reason: reason})
}
```

The above code contains a helper function tries to response an http request with a json containing one generic field that I would like it to be a `string` or an `error`.

But when I try to input a string:

```
string does not implement fmt.Stringer (missing method String)
```

which I find very amusing.

I tried to change `T fmt.Stringer` to `T string | fmt.Stringer`:

```
cannot use fmt.Stringer in union (fmt.Stringer contains methods)
```

I understand the reason is that `string` in golang is a primitive data type without any method, I would like to know if there's a possible way to do this.

---

**Update:**

As @nipuna pointed out in the comment, `error` is not a `Stringer` either.

Comment: `error` also does not implement `fmt.Stringer` interface.

Comment: @nipuna oh that's true... I thought it is but I just realized it's method is `Error` rather than `String`. Thanks! Holy cow, even interfaces in std libs are so confusing. Anyway, I don't think it's the main point here since the generic type could be a union, it's I can't represent a string as a generic, am I right?

Comment: But why do you want a function which can receive a string or an error? How would you distinguish between them anyways? If you really need such behavior, I would suggest to accept two params. The error param can be passed as nil when no error is being passed. In such case (err!=nil), your function would not read the string param, but proceed to the error handling code instead.

Comment: @Sangam yeah but isn't the whole point for go to support generic is to write less code? The function I mentioned currently accepts a `string` type and needs to convert an `error` with `err.Error()`. It works but I think it's convinient to write `upstreamError := DoA(); responseWithError(upstreamError)` and `responseWithError("a const friendly error string")` so I'm tring generics.

Comment: There is no functional code that could treat a `string` and an `error` the same, so a generic that would accept both would not be useful. If you need different behavior based on the type, then generics aren't the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to take a string or an error as a generic parameter?

No. As stated, the constraint you are looking for is `~string | error`, which doesn't work because interfaces with methods can't be used in unions.

And `error` is indeed an interface with the `Error() string` method.

The sensible way to handle this is to drop generics and define `Reason` as a `string`:

```
type ServerError struct {
    Reason string `json:"reason"`
}
```

You can find more details about that here: [Golang Error Types are empty when encoded to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989924/golang-error-types-are-empty-when-encoded-to-json). The tl;dr is that `error` <strike>can't</strike> shouldn't be encoded to JSON directly; you'll eventually have to extract its string message anyway.

So in the end you're going to do something like this with strings:

```
reason := "something was wrong"
c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, ServerError{reason})
```

and something like this with errors:

```
reason := errors.New("something was wrong")
c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, ServerError{reason.Error()})
```